# Friction between $n$ surfaces?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

Since two weeks ago, I have been working on a project where $n$ things are overlap together (with different *coefficients of friction*) for getting the force that's need for pulling them apart.

1. Could you help me? (If all the surface is the same.)
2. Could you help me? (if we have 2 surface with different COF.)

Overlapping cause a degree (consider that).

Comment: I think this needs a diagram, if you want a decent answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Friction forces and sliding slabs](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79173/)

Comment: An answer already exists.

Comment: To which of the items is the force applied? How are the items (masses) positioned? provide a diagram.