# Why is static friction called self adjusting force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, friction

Explain what is limiting force of static friction.

Comment: Dear Nuke, first of all welcome to Physics.SE. Would you please add your own understanding so people have something to criticize. Otherwise, without showing any effort on your side people might just close this question.

Comment: I actually think this is a good question. Perhaps keep the title, and allow the question to be "I have heard static friction called a "self-adjusting force". How can this be? How does the force "know" how large to be? They way I understand it....".

Answer (score 2):

Based on how you phrased the question, I think the answer comes from intuition and definition-chasing.

Static friction: This is a contact force which acts against forces trying to slide two surfaces against each other.

It is limited in maximum magnitude because we don't expect two surfaces to be inexoriably fused, at least in the scales of problems in which static friction matters (static friction does not nucleons together...). There is some maximum static friction, over which you can move the surfaces relative to each other.

I have not heard it called "self-adjusting" myself but that makes sense as well without worrying about microphysics. It prevents the movement of two surfaces, but we know that we can pull harder and harder on two stuck surfaces and they still might not move. We can also *not* pull at all, and they won't move. Thus, static friction must change it's magnitude from 0 to some maximum only according to how hard you pull - thus "self-adjusting".

Answer (score 1):

- Static friction is always less than or equal to some maximum total relative force, that if exceeded will result in the motion of the object.
- The static friction will change both direction and amplitude to keep the object still with respect to whatever is providing the friction.
- So long as the force applied to the object, from another means, is less than or equal to the maximum static friction the static friction itself will change or self adjust to provide an equal and opposite force.
- The maximum possible static friction is directly related to two values, the "force normal" (the perpendicular to surface force of the object on the provider of the static friction), and the "coefficient of static friction" (a value based on many chemical, electromagnetic and/or quantum properties of the objects in contact).

[Check this out if you want to try and get deeper into the rabbit hole.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64780/31516)